# empty results from YouTube API request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube-api

I don't understand why the items array is empty. Can someone tell me what is not working? Thank you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('#infl-yt-label').on('click', function() {
    //$('#infl-inp-search').attr("placeholder","YouTube input...");
    $('#infl-form-ig').hide();
    $('#infl-form-yt').show();
});

$('#infl-it-label').on('click', function() {
    //$('#infl-inp-search').attr("placeholder","Instagram input...");
    $('#infl-form-yt').hide();
    $('#infl-form-ig').show();
});

 $("#searchchannels").on("click", function() {
    console.log($("#infl-inp-search-yt").val());
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?",
        {
            part:"snippet",
            type:"channel",
            q: encodeURIComponent($("#infl-inp-search-yt").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
            key:key
        },
             function(data)
             {
                console.log(data.items)
                 $.each(data.items, function()
                 {
                 console.log(data.items);
                 })
             }

        );//end get
    alert(1);
});//end 

});// end
```

html :

```
        <div class="infl-sociale col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
            <input id="infl-yt" type="radio" name="infl-sociale" value="youtube" checked>
            <label for="infl-yt" id="infl-yt-label"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
            <input id="infl-it" type="radio" name="infl-sociale" value="instagram">
            <label for="infl-it" id="infl-it-label"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        </div>
```

Note: I don't have a script link to the google api link in the header.

Comment: Maybe assync mistake on callback or the callback ins't parsed to JSON.

Comment: you are not passing data in your `each` function, just add `$.each(data.items, function(data)`

Comment: @Grasper, I tried your solution, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the function to properly iterate over the "items" collection.

```
function(data)
{
    console.log(data.items) /* what does this log to the console? */
    $.each(data.items, function(item)
    {
        console.log(item);
    })
}
```

That being said, what is the result of the first `console.log(data.items)`? if this is empty, iterating over it isn't going to do anything. you may also just try `console.log(data)` or look at Chrome debug Network tab to look at the response from the API call.